# Jackson deserialize a date as Integer array in Local datetime/LocalDate

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Java 17, spring-boot 2.7.4 and it's related Spring dependencies.

I have a Kafka consumer that consumes an object representing a date as an Integer array as below:

```
{
    "date": [2022, 9, 21, 21, 28, 37, 9999999]
}
```

I understand that using spring boot I already have `jackson-datatype-jsr310` in my classpath. When I use my `ObjectMapper` to deserialize the object it does not give me as a `LocalDateTime`. How can I achieve this? Do I have to write a custom `LocalDateTime` deserializer?

Plus, how can I use the embedded Kafka json deserializer in order to delegate the mapping that I'm doing manually?

Comment: Why use an array instead of unix epoch or a string, that Jackson can already handle?

Comment: Here's how you customize it https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#tip-json

Comment: @OneCricketeer good question. But I don't have access to the code that produces the Kafka object serialization, I just consume it.

Comment: @OneCricketeer what would be the effect in serialization/deserializarion of other objects that also use Jackson such as objects sent with RestTemplate or the ones received by my rest endpoints? Other thing, an array of Integers is also a timestamp? I thought timestamps were `long`s such as the one returned by `System.currentTimeInMillis()` method.

Comment: I am not well versed in Spring, that link there explicitly extends the Kafka (de)serializer classes, not modifies Spring MVC functions

Comment: Timestamps can be anything, as long as a parser is defined. You simply have `[yyyy, dd, MM, HH, mm, ss, SSS]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer considering your comment, a `LocalDateTime` is also a timestamp since it has its parser, right?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will try your link solution and get back to you.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` has a parse method. But it accepts a string, so you will need a different solution for handling arrays

Comment: You might be interested in this section of the Jackson source https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/2.14/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java#L88-L127

Comment: I didn't explain myself well, I know how to parse this date format into `LocalDateTime`, you don't even need a `DateTimeFormatter`, you can use `LocalDateTime.now(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)` method. I just want to know if giving the concept that you described as a timestamp if `LocalDateTime` can be described also as timestamp.

Comment: I'll check this section of the code out. But I don't think it is being used, otherwise it would return me the date as `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: _if LocalDateTime can be described also as timestamp_ - Yes, but you need to parse the array into that class first. I'm not sure what default deserializers/parsers that Spring/Jackson uses

Comment: It uses the method I previously mentioned in my comments per the sample code you highlighted.